# Visual Studio VSIX project starts up wrong project

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I've been working on two VSIX projects, the first one has been around for a year, and was working fine.  The other one was just started a week ago.  I have debugged both of them in the experimental instance of VS.

Today; however, whenever I start the first project, I get an exception from the 2nd project stating that at XAML load time it can't find a directory.

First, I don't understand why that project is even showing up because I'm not debugging that one.  It shouldn't even be trying to start the 2nd project up..

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug a VSIX project it is installed in the experimental instance of VS and then loaded each time you start the experimental instance.

You can temporarily disable or uninstall the second project in the extension manager to get around this error.

Comment: Root Cause: The 2nd project was throwng an error at load time of the first project because, the experimental instance still had the 2nd project tool window opened in it.  I had deleted all the experimental extensions manually in the appdata\local\Microsoft\visual studio\extensions\14.0Exp folder in attempt to clean things up.  When XAML was loading it couldn't find the files it needed to bring up that 2nd project window.  This is why it "looked" like the wrong project was loading....